# How to stop the debugger from going into delphi given units

Tags: delphi, system, delphi-xe4

My problem is that when ever i try to step using F7 in my delphi debugger it goes into system units like System.SysUtils etc... I dont care about these units I just want to step my own code. How can i turn this function off. I am using Delphi XE4 Architect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid trace into the Delphi RTL units when you press <kbd>F7</kbd>, You must uncheck the option *Use debug .dcus*

[image]